# Cannot find symbol when calling class?

Tags: java

I am new to java and have a question about input validation. I am attempting to call two classes (by the names of ValidCustomerType and ValidSubtotal) that will validate the input of this application. The code for the main classes are as follows:

Main Class:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InvoiceApp
{
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    static NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    static NumberFormat percent = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
    static CostelloHeading ch = new CostelloHeading();
    static CostelloDate cd = new CostelloDate();
    static ValidCustomerType vct = new ValidCustomerType();
    static ValidSubtotal vst = new ValidSubtotal();



    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DecimalFormat cf = new DecimalFormat("$#,##0.00");
        DecimalFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
        ///NumberFormat cf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        // NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        NumberFormat pf = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();

        pf.setMaximumFractionDigits(1);
        pf.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);
        //nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        //nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

        customerType = vct.getValidCustomerType(sc);
        subtotal = vst.getValidSubtotal(sc);

        String choice = "y";
        ch.getHeading("Assignment 4 - Validate Input Data");
        System.out.printf("  Invoice Application \n\n");

        while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
        {

            // get the input from the user
            System.out.print("  Enter customer type (C, J, R or T) or an X to Exit ->   ");
            String customerType = sc.next();
            if (customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("X"))
                {
                    System.out.printf("\n  Program terminated by the User.\n");
                    CostelloDate.printfDate();
                    CostelloDate.printfTime();
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            System.out.print("  Enter subtotal ->                                     ");
            double subtotal = sc.nextDouble();

            // get the discount percent
            double discountPercent = getDiscountPercent(customerType, subtotal);

            // calculate the discount amount and total
            double discountAmount = subtotal * discountPercent;
            double total = subtotal - discountAmount;

            // format and display the results

            System.out.printf("\n  Customer Type Selected:  %s\n",  customerType.toUpperCase());
            System.out.printf("%12s %10s %12s %10s\n", "Invoice", "Discount", "Discount", "Billed");
            System.out.printf("%12s %10s %12s %10s\n", "Amount", "Percent", "Amount", "Amount");
            System.out.printf("%12s %10s %12s %10s\n", "--------", "--------", "--------", "--------");
            System.out.printf("  $%,9.2f  %8.1f%%  $ %,8.2f  $ %8.2f\n\n", subtotal,(discountPercent * 100), discountAmount, total);

        }

    }
    private static double getDiscountPercent(String customerType, double subtotal)
    {
                    double discountPercent = 0;
            if (customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
            {
                discountPercent = .188;
            }
            else if (customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("J"))
            {
                discountPercent = .23;
            }
            else if (customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("R"))
            {
                if (subtotal < 100)
                discountPercent = .055;
                else if (subtotal >= 100 && subtotal < 250)
                    discountPercent = .121;
                else if (subtotal >= 250 && subtotal < 500)
                    discountPercent = .222;
                else discountPercent = .333;

            }
            else if (customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("T"))
            {
                if (subtotal < 500)
                    discountPercent = .404;
                else discountPercent = .525;
            }
            else
            {
                discountPercent = .1;
            }
            return discountPercent;
    }
}
```

I keep getting an error 'cannot find symbol' when attempting to call and use these classes. Is there something big that I am missing?

Comment: what symbol. show us the error stack trace

Comment: where are the classes `static CostelloHeading ch = new CostelloHeading();
    static CostelloDate cd = new CostelloDate();
    static ValidCustomerType vct = new ValidCustomerType();
    static ValidSubtotal vst = new ValidSubtotal();` - are they in another jar or another package?

Comment: You haven't imported them?

Comment: I have these files in the 'default package' :  CostelloDate.java   CostelloHeading.java  ValidCustomerType.java and ValidSubtotal.java

Comment: the class files mentioned above in the default package are all properly coded

Comment: error stack trace.. that tells u which symbol

Comment: Also, I am using NetBeans IDE 8.0

Comment: that doesn't matter. All that matters is Java and its version

Comment: im not sure how to look up the error stack trace.. all i know is an error pops up next to the code: 'customerType = vct.getValidCustomerType(sc);' and it says 'cannot find symbol variable customer type'

Comment: got it .. customerType = vct.getValidCustomerType(sc);  customerType  is not declared. Declare teh type of it

Comment: eg: `ValidCustomerType customerType = vct.getValidCustomerType(sc);`

Comment: Infact your program is not using it thereafter!. but that fix ur issue

Comment: thanks prash...but where and how do i declare it? if you scroll down to my 'while' code, i declared it with the code 'String customerType = sc.next();'

Comment: i will continue in answer section. too much comments is not advisable. or else SO recommend the discussion to chat. pls see answer updated

Answer (score 0):

This is your code

`customerType = vct.getValidCustomerType(sc);`

You get "cannot find symbol customerType " because customerType is not declared.

Declare it like this, or like how you did for the rest of the variables,

```
String customerType = vct.getValidCustomerType(sc);
```

Note: Infact your program is not using it thereafter!. but that is not the current issue, that is related to unused code.

Edit based on your comment

> but where and how do i declare it? if you scroll down to my 'while'
>   code, i declared it with the code 'String customerType = sc.next();'

That is in different local **scope**. The scope of `customerType` in  `String customerType = sc.next();` is a local scope only inside that while loop.

Basically your code should be like this,

```
....
String customerType;
customerType = vct.getValidCustomerType(sc);

...

while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
{
// get the input from the user
System.out.print("  Enter customer type (C, J, R or T) or an X to Exit ->   ");
customerType = sc.next();
if (customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("X"))
......
```

Comment: thanks prash, i changed this in the code, and the error i am getting is: "incompatible types: String cannot be converted to ValidCustomerType"

Comment: retry as mentioned above

Comment: hmm prash i tried as mentioned above, but on the line "customerType = vct.getValidCustomerType(sc);" i continue to get the error "incompatible types: String cannot be converted to ValidCustomerType" as well as all subsequent uses of "customerType"

Comment: I thought customerType is of type `ValidCustomerType`. But it was indeed `String`!!  you didn't mention that when I asked you to declare the variable. But I should have understood by the code `equalsIgnoreCase` because it is java.lang.String.equalsIgnoreCase :) .. cool. it should be ok now